# Score isn't showing in guiText

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have guiTexts called scoreLevel1, scoreLevel2 where i want to show the score from the right levels but it isn't showing any text or scores... There are no build errors.  How do I make it show up as expected?

```
var Score : int;

function Update () {
    Score -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    guiText.text = "Score: "+Score;
    TimerOfDeath();
}
```

**HighScores.js**:

```
//run at start if score doesn't exist yet to initialise playerPref
function Start(){
    if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore"))
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore", 0);
}

//run when level is completed
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        Score = gameObject.Find("ScoreCount").GetComponent("ScoringPts").Update("Score");
        if(Score > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore", Score);
        }
    }
}
```

**GetHighScores.js**:

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {
    var hscount = 1;
    var iterations = 1;
    var maxIterations = 5;
    var findtext = gameObject.Find("scoreLevel"+(hscount));
    while(hscount < 5 && iterations < maxIterations){
        if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Level"+(hscount)+"HighScore")){
            findtext.guiText.text = "Level"+(hscount)+ ": " + PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level"+(hscount)+"HighScore");
            hscount++;
        }
        iterations++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that the score isn't being calculated correctly or that guiText isn't being rendered anywhere?

Comment: In GetHighScores.js you have an error: while(hscount < 5 && -->iterations > maxIterations<--(this is false)) - your while never run

Comment: i have guiTexts called scoreLevel1,2,3,4,5. in for example scoreLevel1 i want to show the score that the player got in level 1.

vsenik i changed iterations > maxIterations to iterations < maxIterations and it's still not adding the scores to text

Comment: Your if wrong too. if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Level"+(hscount)+"HighScore")) - mean if there is no record in playerprefs then try to use it - it makes no sense